# How is it possible to join existing Kubernetes cluster with Ubuntu running on WSL2?

Tags: docker, ubuntu, kubernetes, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I installed Ubuntu on WSL2 in the environment shown below.
When I tried to register this Ubuntu as a worker node for Kubernetes cluster with the procedures shown below,
there happened an error.
How is it possible to register Ubuntu?

[my environment]

- Windows 10 Pro Insider Preview 1903 build 18922.1000

  - WSL2
- WSL2 Ubuntu

  - Docker 18.09.5-ce
  - kubectl 1.14.3
  - kubeadm 1.14.3
  - kubelet 1.14.3
- Master Node

  - Ubuntu Server 18.04.2
  - Docker 18.09.5-ce
  - kubectl 1.14.3
  - kubeadm 1.14.3
  - kubelet 1.14.3

[my procedures]

1. run Ubuntu on WSL2
2. start Docker Service

   ```
   $ sudo service docker start
   ```
3. create a token to join the cluster on MasterNode

   ```
   $ kubeadm token generate
   $ kubeadm token create [key] --print-join-command
   ```
4. execute the following command on Ubuntu

   ```
   $ sudo kubeadm join [masterIP]:6443 --token [token] --discovery-token-ca-cert-hash [hash]
   ```

[the result]

```
[preflight] Running pre-flight checks
    [WARNING IsDockerSystemdCheck]: detected "cgroupfs" as the
Docker cgroup driver. The recommended driver is "systemd". Please
follow the guide at https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/cri/
[preflight] The system verification failed. Printing the output from the verification:
KERNEL_VERSION: 4.19.43-microsoft-standard
CONFIG_NAMESPACES: enabled
CONFIG_NET_NS: enabled
CONFIG_PID_NS: enabled
CONFIG_IPC_NS: enabled
CONFIG_UTS_NS: enabled
CONFIG_CGROUPS: enabled
CONFIG_CGROUP_CPUACCT: enabled
CONFIG_CGROUP_DEVICE: enabled
CONFIG_CGROUP_FREEZER: enabled
CONFIG_CGROUP_SCHED: enabled
CONFIG_CPUSETS: enabled
CONFIG_MEMCG: enabled
CONFIG_INET: enabled
CONFIG_EXT4_FS: enabled
CONFIG_PROC_FS: enabled
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_TARGET_REDIRECT: enabled
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_COMMENT: not set
CONFIG_OVERLAY_FS: enabled
CONFIG_AUFS_FS: not set - Required for aufs.
CONFIG_BLK_DEV_DM: enabled
DOCKER_VERSION: 18.09.5
DOCKER_GRAPH_DRIVER: overlay2
OS: Linux
CGROUPS_CPU: enabled
CGROUPS_CPUACCT: enabled
CGROUPS_CPUSET: enabled
CGROUPS_DEVICES: enabled
CGROUPS_FREEZER: enabled
CGROUPS_MEMORY: enabled
error execution phase preflight: [preflight] Some fatal errors occurred:
    [ERROR Service-Docker]: docker service is not active, please run 'systemctl start docker.service'
    [ERROR FileContent--proc-sys-net-bridge-bridge-nf-call-iptables]: /proc/sys/net/bridge/bridge-nf-call-iptables does not exist
    [ERROR SystemVerification]: unexpected kernel config: CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_COMMENT
[preflight] If you know what you are doing, you can make a check non-fatal with `--ignore-preflight-errors=...`
```

Comment: It's showing 3 errors, docker not running, missing `bridge-nf-call-iptables` and the kernel config `CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_COMMENT`. You can also ignore all of those errors by adding `--ignore-preflight-errors=all`

Comment: This may help https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4165

Comment: @Crou Thank you. I added `--ignore-preflight-errors=all` but `[WARNING SystemVerification]: unexpected kernel config: CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_COMMENT` shown. I will check [github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4165](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4165).

Comment: @Biswapriyo Thank you. I will check [github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4165](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4165).

Comment: Problem solved. I installed [genie](https://github.com/arkane-systems/genie) and reinstalled docker(after remove /var/lib/docker). Command `kubeadm join` success with output  `This node has joined the cluster`.